# position: fixed doesn't work!

Tags: html, css

For some reason, position:absolute works where position:fixed does not. When I use postion: absolute, my div (called "chatBox") displays with the proper margins. When I use position: fixed, my div just appears in the top left corner.

Here is the page in question, with a lot of the code cleaned up for easy review: http://www.mytrafficman.net/index9.php

I need position:fixed to work!

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: If `position: absolute;` works, why do you have to use `position: fixed;`?

Comment: IE8. Chrome and FF position right, except that the #chatBox is only half as long as it should be, so it appears that the background of the box is too short!

Comment: I need position:fixed to work so that the box positions itself relative to the viewport, or visible area of the page.

Comment: -1 for removing the link to the original code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify a doctype.

At the top of the page type in `<!doctype html>` and it will start working in IE as well.

For more info on doctypes refer [to this page](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_doctype.asp)

Comment: I added a doctype and it caused it to break in all browsers. Not only that, but it screwed the box up so it is all squished (ignores width, height, etc.) Here is the same page with doctype: http://www.mytrafficman.net/index10.php

Comment: @Michael Sounds like someones was coding to quirks-mode before :-)

Comment: It seems so simple and it's amazing no one can figure it out.

Comment: @Michael the height for the messageWindow div is set to 250. You need to add 'px' to that to make it 250px. The same thing goes for top and right, width. You basically need to define what units of measurement the browser should use.

Comment: Actually I still need the doctype. Whatever that is. But between the px and the doctype, it all works now :)

Comment: @Michael doctype is used to make a complaint HTML page. It tells the browser what language the page is written in and is used to render the content and the markup properly.